# python string template: multiline substitution with correct indentation

Tags: python, templates, newline

I'm using [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings)s to generate Python code. A template might looks like

```py
import numpy

def main():
    ${content}
    return
```

When substituting `${content}` with a multiline string, the result is

```py
 import numpy

 def main():
     a = 1
     b = 2
     print(a + b)
     return
```

Makes sense, but of course isn't what I want. Instead of concatenating the statements with a newline, I could use `;` , but for the sake of readability, I'd like to have all newlines padded with the correct indent.

How can I substitute `${content}` with a newline string and correct indentation?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `string.Template` for my code generation as well and also needed to get the indentation from the template. 
My solution is to subclass `string.Template` and add a method to get the indentation there.

If you store your multiline string as a list of lines, you can then use `'\n' + indent` to join this list.

Using your example the code could look like this:

```py
from string import Template
import re

class MyTemplate(Template):
    def get_indentation(self):
        self.indentation = {}
        # self.pattern is the regular expression Template uses to find the substitution patterns
        # self.template is the template string given in the constructor
        for match in self.pattern.finditer(self.template):
            symbol = match.group()
            # search whitespace between the start of a line and the current substitution pattern
            # '^' matches start of line only with flag re.MULTILINE
            pattern = r"^(\s*)" + re.escape(symbol)
            indent = re.search(pattern, self.template, re.MULTILINE)
            self.indentation[symbol] = indent.group(1)

tpl = """\
import numpy

def main():
    ${content}
    return
"""

template = MyTemplate(tpl)
template.get_indentation()

content_list = [
    "a = 1",
    "b = 2",
    "print(a + b)",
]

join_str = "\n" + template.indentation["${content}"]
content = join_str.join(content_list)
print(template.substitute(content=content))
```

`MyTemplate.get_indentation()` compiles a dictionary with the substitution patterns as keys and the whitespace from the start of the line to the start of the substitution pattern as value. So in this case the dictionary will be:

```py
template.indentation = {
    "${content}": "    "
}
```

Note that the code is not very efficient as it uses a regular expression search over the whole template string for every substitution pattern found in this string.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few options, no magic 'print this and correctly indent it' methods though.

1) 
You can include the spaces/newlines in your multiline string like so:

```
"""a = 1
    b = 2
    print(a + b)"""
```

2) 
You could use [autopep8](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8), and run it over the generated python file.

3)
Or instead of keeping it as a single multiline string, you could keep it as a list of strings and do something like:

```
def assemble_code_string(content_list, indent):
    # assemble the content_list into a single string, prepending the indent value of spaces to each content_list
    return '\n'.join(["%s%s"%(' '*indent, line) for line in content_list])
```

and then use that as your `${content}`. This is quite simple though as it assumes all lines in your content list will be prepended with the same indent. I'm sure you could build on it if you needed to.

Comment: Not sure about (1) and (3). After all, you don't know the indent of the template when generating the code, do you? Perhaps it should be possible to read that from the file. (2) sounds good, but won't be sufficient in many situations. Unindented code could be legal, just not what is intended.

Comment: Re 2 that's true, but in your simple example case above the indented `return` might be enough for autopep8 to figure it out. I don't know how much code you're attempting to template at once, if it's multiple methods in a single `${content}` then it might fail.  That's what I was getting at with 3), separate your content by common indent, then template into dest file using `assemble_code_string` with that indent. Like I said, no nice neat answer afaik.